# Intersect not working if target range gets bigger

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to VBA and I need help with this please.

I have a private sub within a sheet and I want it to autofill formulas adjacent to a dynamic named range, if the size of the range changes.

**(edit) I am pasting data from another worksheet into this one columns A-M. My dynamic range is defined as =OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,13). The first If statement should exit the sub if there is no data in column M and I had the destination calculating the last row of column M because I want to fill the formulas in N:O so that they cover the same number of rows as column M.**

This is my code and it works if the size of the range gets smaller (i.e. if I delete rows from the bottom), but not if it gets bigger and I can't work out why!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Me.Range("M2").Value = "" Then

    MsgBox "No Data!"

    Exit Sub

Else

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("rngOracleInvoices")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim Lrows As Long

        Lrows = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

        Me.Range(Me.Cells(3, 14), Me.Cells(Lrows, "O")).ClearContents
        Me.Range("N2:O2").AutoFill Destination:=Me.Range("N2:O" & Me.Range("M" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    End If

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I put the last bit into a separate macro to test if it works on its own and for some reason, when I run it, the autofill goes all the way up to row 1 and overwrites the formulas, which is weird because I use that code a lot and it's never done that before. What have I done??!!

Also, if there is a better way to do the autofill I'd appreciate if someone could let me know what it is because I just cobbled that together from bits I found on forums :)

Thanks,

Soph

Comment: column M is the last column of my data range, so if cells M2 is blank I want to exit the sub

Answer (score 0):

In this line `Me.Range("N2:O2").AutoFill Destination:=Me.Range("N2:O" & Me.Range("M" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` you calculate your last row on the column **M** so if it is empty it'll give you `1` and autofill your formula on row 1.

So start by calculating it on the good column (my guess is **O**)

You can also simply define an Integer variable to test it and if it is inferior to 2, change it back to 2, 3, 4 or whatever you want.

*For your dynamic range, we might need some precision.*

And for the `AutoFill`, you could just **select manually the range `N2:02` and then double-click on the bottom right square** (the one you drag to autofill) and it'll autofill as long as there data in adjacent cells! (give it a try ;) )

Comment: You can edit your question and include that info into it so that others will see it too!

Comment: I am pasting data from another worksheet into this one columns A-M. My dynamic range is defined as =OFFSET($A$1,1,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-1,13). The first If statement should exit the sub if there is no data in column M and I had the destination calculating the last row of column M because I want to fill the formulas in N:O so that they cover the same number of rows as column M, is that not right?